# Migrate and run asp.net web api core project written on windows to linux

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a asp.net web api core project written on windows and i want to run this application on linux. Is this possible?

Comment: It will run on linux unless you are using something which has a dependency on full .net framework.

Comment: How can i run it on linux? only with Mono?

Answer (score 0):

Paltform independance was only a dream that never came true for the .NET Framework. While Mono came close-ish, you had to develop for Mono first.

However Platform indepedance **is** true for .NET Core.

Here are the Microsoft Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore21

And the download page for the linux version:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

So from this point on, it will be mostly a mater of Linux administration and small details (wich 3rd Party or .NET Framework code you might have used).